# Cannot set property 'display' of undefined when i use java script

Tags: javascript, css, html

i trying to change css using java script but it did not work.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('chirag');
    var check = document.getElementById('chk1');

    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i+=1){
   if(check.checked){
        x.style.display = 'none';
         }
          else {
         x.style.display = 'block';
     }
 }
}
```

```css
.chirag{
   display: none;
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  id="chk1" value="Plate" onclick="myFunction()"> Plate  <br> 

<div id="plan_detail" class="chirag">
</div>
```

i try to add javascript function on checkbox event. how can i fix it and change the css property

Comment: `x` is a list of elements, not an element itself. Maybe you meant `x[i].style.display` ?

Comment: yes @JaredSmith thanks... it's work

Answer (score 2):

You were missing the "i" on the for cycle:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('chirag');
    var check = document.getElementById('chk1');

    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i+=1){
   if(!check.checked){
     x[i].style.display = 'none';
   } else {
     x[i].style.display = 'block';
   }
 }
}
```

```css
.chirag{
   display: none;
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  id="chk1" value="Plate" onclick="myFunction()"> Plate  <br> 

<div id="plan_detail" class="chirag">
   test
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the integer "i" of the loop as index of the array of elements "x"

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('chirag');
    var check = document.getElementById('chk1');

    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i+=1){
   if(check.checked){
        x[i].style.display = 'none';
         }
          else {
         x[i].style.display = 'block';
     }
 }
}
```

```css
.chirag{
   display: none;
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  id="chk1" value="Plate" onclick="myFunction()"> Plate  <br> 

<div id="plan_detail" class="chirag">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**javascript:**

You miss `i` index:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('chirag');
    var check = document.getElementById('chk1');
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i+=1) {
        if(check.checked)
           x[i].style.display = 'block';
        else 
            x[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('chirag');
    var check = document.getElementById('chk1');
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i+=1) {
        if(check.checked)
           x[i].style.display = 'block';
        else 
            x[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
.chirag {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  id="chk1" value="Plate" onclick="myFunction()"> Plate  <br> 

<div id="plan_detail" class="chirag">
   Hello
</div>
```

**With jquery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chk1').click(function(){
        $('.chirag').toggle();
    })
})
```

```css
.chirag {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<input type="checkbox"  id="chk1" value="Plate"> Plate  <br> 

<div id="plan_detail" class="chirag">
   Hello
</div>
```